# Angular problem Subject with getClickEvent

Tags: angular, service

I have to components in Angular, one with the template of my app, and the other with a modal. I have implemented a shared service to set and get click event like this:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SharedServiceService {
  constructor() {}

  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  sendClickEvent(id) {
    this.subject.next();
  }
  getClickEvent(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I would like to open the modal when I click in a button of my app which get an id in parameter :

```
<a (click)="onOpenModal(pension.id)">  //HTML of my template
  onOpenModal(id) {
this.sharedService.sendClickEvent(id); //.ts of my template
  }
```

But the problem is that I would like to get this id, create a new function in component modal, call her in my modal HTML, and resend this function to my main component :

```
    export class ModalSupprimerComponent implements OnInit {
  clickEventsubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedServiceService) {
    this.clickEventsubscription = this.sharedService.getClickEvent(id).subscribe(() => {}); //problem here with id
  }

  onDelete(id) {
    this.sharedService.sendClickEvent(id);
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And my modal HTML is like that :

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Confirmer l'abandon" (click)="onDelete(id)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't pushing the `id` in the shared service function. Try the following

```js
sendClickEvent(id) {
  this.subject.next(id); // <-- push id here
}
```

Comment: But after pushing id,  there is even a problem : On my modal component the id is not known when I get it

Comment: Could you please elaborate 'not known when I get it'? What exactly is the error and where do you get it in the class?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to pass id to Subject:

```js
this.subject.next();
```

And in place where you subscribed to that Subject you can receive id as callback's argument:

```js
this.clickEventsubscription = this.sharedService.getClickEvent().subscribe((id) => {
// here you can do: 
// this.id = id; (or something else)
});
```

In callback you can do whatever you want with this id. For example, assign to class property. Moreover, note that **getClickEvent** don't accept any parameter, so you need to remove id to avoid Typescript errors.

Comment: Okay that functions, but I have an other problem because, I make ( a send ( to modal), a get ( in modal), a send (to component), and a get (in component), And so the algorithme try to delete two times, In there a mean to manage this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve... You'd like to send some data back to component from your modal?